# Stuck globe on overhead light, how to remove, clean, and prevent ants getting inside!

Tags: light-fixture

I installed several of these light fixtures recently ([LED fixture](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-11-in-120-Watt-Equivalent-Satin-Bronze-Integrated-LED-Flush-Mount-with-Frosted-White-Glass-Shade-HB1022C-34/310700110?cm_mmc=ecc-_-STH_DELIVERY_COMPLETE-_-V1_M1_CA-_-Product_URL&ecc_ord=WJ33093479&ecc_id=16840c73384a9e33effb8e457961dd37fbe1d03bc0da2f5e4a1d24bfb03a4fc4)).  They installed easily and have worked great for several months.  The other day we noticed a few ants had crawled from the attic down into the light fixture, died, and collected in the bottom of the globe.  They entered (we assume) through the unused screw holes and the larger hole in the center of the back of the fixture.
[image]

I tried the obvious thing, which was to remove the globe to clean it out.  For some reason it had stuck to the back of the fixture so tightly that I could not rotate it to unlock it.  Eventually the entire fixture came loose from the ceiling even though I had installed it very securely.  Once the circuit was shut off and disconnected I tried again -- with the help of another adult! -- to remove the globe but it is still stuck tight.  I don't think we could have twisted any harder without breaking the glass globe.  I suspect the temperature may have warped the fixture?

In any case, what do I do now?  Does this sound like a manufacturer defect (it's still under warranty)?  Can I tape over the holes shown in the image above to keep future critters out, or would that cause the device to overheat?  Or, more simply, is there some other way to remove the globe?  The globe simply twists on and a little notch catches to hold it in place.  Getting it off is not so simple!

[image]

Comment: Might have some kind of a spring type lock in it keeping it in place.  Might need a push/pull or squeeze action to unlock.  Should not be struck.  You are turning it the right way?

Comment: If there is a spring type lock in it, it's not mentioned in the manual nor is there a visible way of releasing it.  There is nothing to hold onto; both the globe and the fixture are smooth and round.  I wasn't going to strike it...  I am unable to turn it in any direction...

Comment: Try squirting a little WD-40  in that seam with the fixture upside down. There cold be ants in the seam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If cleaning the globe is more complicated than installing the whole luminaire then I'd say it's defective and time to ask the manufacturer about that.  And buy a better product.  Even the cheap ones usually come with an obvious nut, screw, or spring clip that can be detached without any fuss.

Comment: I don't like this answer because now I have to replace the lights, but you are probably correct!  Thank you.  Would never have imagined this would be a thing.